# Javascript framework

Tags: javascript

which javascript framework can be used for all browsers

Comment: "all" browsers? Or "most common"? Yahoo! reported that they get about 10.000 unique user agent strings on their pages...that's a lot of different browser setups. (yeah, most of them are probably spambots, but still...)

Comment: Since "all browsers" includes those browsers that don't support JavaScript at all (yes, there are such browsers) I'd say: no JavaScript framework supports all browsers.

Comment: Last time I tried using jQuery on NCSA Mosaic, it didn't work very well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cross browser JavaScript frameworks: Browser support (from what i can discover pls update in comments)

- Prototype Internet Explorer (IE) 6 +, Firefix (FF) 1+, Safari 2+, Opera (o) 9.25+, Chrome (c) 1+
- script.aculo.us IE 6 +, FF 1+, S 2+, O 9.25+, c 1+
- jQuery IE 6 +, FF 2+, S 3+, O 9+, C 1+
- Yahoo! User Interface Library IE 6 +, FF 3+, S 3+, O 9+, C unknown
- MooTools IE 6 +, FF 1.5+, S 2+, O 9+, C unknown
- Ext JS IE 6 +, FF 1+, S 2+, O 9.25, C 1+
- moo.fx
- Rico
- Qooxdoo IE 6 +, FF 1.5+, S 3+, O 9+, C 1+
- The Dojo Toolkit IE 6 +, FF 2+, S 3.2+, O 9.6+, C 1+

I've used

- jQuery
- yUI

but I always go back to jQuery.

It worth pointing out that different frameworks have different strengths, so work out what you want and find the best framework for you.

Comment: Could you mention shortly what cross-browser means in this context? I guess, it's "IE6+ and FF2+ and Opera9+ and Safari3+ and Chrome1+", isn't it?

Comment: You forgot BBC's Glow. Now with even more cross-browseriness!

Answer (score 6):

Many of them. You would be better asking which ones do not support all browsers. Furthermore, 'all browsers' is a bit vague, do you mean 'all *current* versions', 'all versions for the last x years' or what exactly?

If you're talking about recent, popular, reasonably current and sensible ones, others have pointed out jQuery and Mootools. There's also [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), and plenty more. You will have to decide on which best fits your purpose or programming style.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery, mootools, there are plenty of them.

There is also Glow, BBC's javascript framework which works in Safari 2 and IE 5.5, other frameworks don't support all features in such old browsers.

Comment: jQuery for me is the best but there are so many of them nowadays. YUI,ExtJS,jQuery,MooTools are all good cross browser javascript libraries

Comment: Have the BBC published Glow? (I understood from diffrent BBC blogs that they wouldn't because they had no way of supporting the community.

Comment: Yes they have, a few days ago: http://www.bbc.co.uk/glow/docs/articles/getting_started.shtml

Comment: I'm out of date BBC Glow (http://www.bbc.co.uk/glow/) HOW COOL

Comment: I mean, it's okay, but doubt it will have big community. If the base grows and there will be plugins available, I will actually consider using it ;)

Comment: I wonder if the traction of the appeal of the BBC website(s) will push the design community into using Glow? Worth a look though especially if it activly supports older browsers.

Comment: @Matt: "(I understood from diffrent BBC blogs that they wouldn't because they had no way of supporting the community)" - I was talking to one of the Glow team's lead developers at a conference the other week; they actually wanted to release it a while back, but something went wrong with their CDN (Content Distribution Network) and they had to wait until that was stabilised before they could launch ;-)

Comment: why didn't glow go all the way back to supporting browsers that don't even have javascript? (there's a point there)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery, MooTools, Dojo, YUI, Prototype and more are all  cross-browser compatible. Please formulate your question to something less general, such as what you want to do with the framework.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, jQuery, MooTools or prototype are cross browser.

Answer (score 0):

All of the frameworks are pretty much compatible with most major browsers.
Take your pic yui, dojo, extjs, jslib, jQuery, mootools, prototype.

It would kind of defeat the purpose of developing a js lib if they did not work x-browser.